# cakephpでcss,javascriptを適応させる

Tags: javascript, php, css, cakephp

app/MySample/index.ctp
上記のファイルにcssを適応する場合、どのようにするのが適切でしょうか？
app/MySampleにcssのフォルダを作り、その中にcssファイルを入れ、Controllerにecho $this->Html->css('sample');とすればいいのでしょうか？
同様に、JSの適応のさせ方も知りたいです。
詳しい方、ご教示ください。

Comment: ファイルパスについて、正しくは `app/View/MySample/index.ctp` でよかったでしょうか。

Answer (score 1):

CakePHPにおいて、公開ファイル（cssやjavascript、画像など）の設置先は`APP/webroot/`になります。

cssであれば、`APP/webroot/css/`配下に配置します。

例えば、

```
echo $this->Html->css('sample');
```

であれば、`APP/webroot/css/sample.css`が読み出されます。

`HtmlHelper::css()`メソッドの挙動、オプションについて、まずは以下のマニュアルを読んでください。

HtmlHelper — CakePHP Cookbook 2.x ドキュメント
http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/ja/core-libraries/helpers/html.html#HtmlHelper::css

また、JavaScriptファイルの読み込みは、`HtmlHelper::script()`を使用します。
JavaScriptファイルの配置先は`APP/webroot/js/`です。

こちらも使い方はマニュアルを参考にしてください。

HtmlHelper — CakePHP Cookbook 2.x ドキュメント 
http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/ja/core-libraries/helpers/html.html#HtmlHelper::script